# DIV Positions differs depending on content length

Tags: html, css, position

I'm working on my travel homepage and faceing a problem with my DIV containers.
Depending on the length of the content, the position of the following container changes.
It's hard to explain - please checkout http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch
As long as all containers contains a two-line description text, it looks fine - but as soon as the description length changes, the containers jump around.

This is the related part of the CSS

```css
div.roundobject {
    height: 10em;
    width: 30em;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    position: relative;
    margin:   0.8em 1.6em 0.8em 0em; /*top - right - bottom - left*/
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    border-radius: 5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5em;
}

a:hover > div.roundobject > div > h2   {
    color: #990000;
}

div.roundobject > div   {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 11em;
}

div.roundobject > img   {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -2px;
}

div.roundobject > div > img.newObjectMarker {
    z-index: 99;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    max-width: 2em;
}

div.roundobject > div > h2    {
    display: inline; 
}

div.roundobject > div > span  {
    display: block;
}
```

At the moment the content is build like that:

```html
<a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/europa"><div class="roundobject colorborder"><img class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//photo/thumb/3-6"><div><h2>Europa</h2><img class="newObjectMarker" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/new.png"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l</span></div></div></a>
```

*(the easiest would be if you use any dev tools from browser to see)*

Any hint for the solution?

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: One solution for this is after some length of text you can put dots to rest
like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur...." since anyway the user can read the text by going inside the post

Comment: Specify the `vertical-align` you want for the `a` elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: @ShahajiDeshmukh: I'd like that all 3 of the round objects on a line are at the same vertical position. At the moment every item got a own position

Comment: @Sachi.Dila I will do something like this at the end anyway - to limit the maximum length to as example 2 rows.
But this will not solve the problem, because some of the items does not contain a description at all

Comment: @MarkusH. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> misorude: Specify the vertical-align you want for the a elements.

I needed to add the vertical-align to to "main div" class "roundobject" - now it works fine.

Thanks to misorude

Answer (score 0):

add following line to all the divs:

```
div{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: I added the line to both involved DIVs - unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `div.roundobject > div{ padding-right: 2em; }` will resolve your issue. Below are the updated code:

```css
div.roundobject {
    height: 10em;
    width: 30em;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    position: relative;
    margin:   0.8em 1.6em 0.8em 0em; /*top - right - bottom - left*/
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    border-radius: 5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5em;
}

a:hover > div.roundobject > div > h2   {
    color: #990000;
}

div.roundobject > div   {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 11em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}

div.roundobject > img   {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -2px;
}

div.roundobject > div > img.newObjectMarker {
    z-index: 99;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    max-width: 2em;
}

div.roundobject > div > h2    {
    display: inline; 
}

div.roundobject > div > span  {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HoHoUn - Gruppen</title>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/css/format.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/MultisizeIcon.ico">
    <script src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//js/TileTextOnHover.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<body background="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/background.jpg">
<div class="contentcontainer alignoncenter padding15">
<header>

<a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/">
    <img id="logo" class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/Logo.png">
</a>

<span id="headertext">Reisen um die Welt mit Sabrina und Markus</span>

</header>
<article>

<a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/asien"><div class="roundobject colorborder" style="
    position: relative;
"><img class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//photo/thumb/2-4"><div style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
"><h2>Asien</h2><img class="newObjectMarker" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/new.png"><span>Reisen in die Länder der aufgehenden Sonne.</span></div></div></a><a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/europa"><div class="roundobject colorborder"><img class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//photo/thumb/3-6"><div><h2>Europa</h2><img class="newObjectMarker" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/new.png"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l</span></div></div></a><a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/nordamerika"><div class="roundobject colorborder"><img class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//photo/thumb/4-8"><div><h2>Nordamerika</h2><img class="newObjectMarker" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/img/new.png"></div></div></a><a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/ozeanien"><div class="roundobject colorborder"><img class="colorborder" src="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch//photo/thumb/5-10"><div><h2>Ozeanien</h2><span>Auch eine Insel kann schön sein.</span></div></div></a><a href="http://reisen-test.hoho06.ch/group/details/tagesausfluege"><div class="roundobject colorborder"><img class="colorborder" src=""><div><h2>Tagesausflüge</h2><span>Die kurzen Ausflüge, welche die Gruppe "Europa" sprengen würde...</span></div></div></a>
</article><footer>
<p class="tripfooter">© Design by Markus H. / © Content by Sabrina &amp; Markus</p>
</footer>
</div>

</body></html>
```